# General Campaign Measurement Google Tag Manager for Apps

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to find some documentation/examples on how to implement General Campaign Measurement (not Google Play Campaign Attribution) using Google Tag Manager for apps.

This link (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns) talks about how to do this using just the GA SDK. The article basically says that you need to manually extract the utm parameters from the Intent object and pass them to the GA hit.

So is there any way to achieve this manual utm parameter parsing using GTM for apps? Are there any examples/demos of how to do this? This seems like a pretty basic and essential requirement of any app, but for whatever reason I can't find anything about it online.

Also, how is session management handled with GTM for apps. I know that EasyTracker starts a new session when the app has been in the background for 30 seconds or more (by default). Does GTM for apps use EasyTracker behind the scenes? If not, are we supposed to manually control sessions using the Session Control field under More Settings/Basic Configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to map campaign parameters variables such as source and medium yourself, that's how GTM provides flexibility. On Android, we usually implement a function like :-

```
 public static void trackCampaign(String uri_string)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_string);

    DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(getAppContext()).getDataLayer();
    dataLayer.pushEvent("campaignTracking",
                                          DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", screenName,
                                                                        "source", uri.getQueryParameter("utm_source"),
                                                                        "medium", uri.getQueryParameter("utm_medium"));
}
```

On the GTM dashboard you can use the "Fields to set" parameters to set campaign parameters such as source and medium. Please see the image below for reference.
[image]

Comment: Where did you find the parameter for campaign and source like &cn &cs?

Comment: Hi @MarkMolina You can find the comprehensive list of parameter references on this page. [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en).

Comment: Also, please upvote if you find the answer correct :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that GTM for apps does not yet support general campaign tracking in GA.

Comment: Hi @faridghar how did you experience that? Is it documented anywhere? We're currently testing this setup but without any luck. Thanks

Comment: @micmdk you should be able to manually extract the utm parameters from the deep link and then push them onto the GTM dataLayer with a custom event (e.g. event : deepLinkOpened). You would then have to configure a GA event tag to fire in response to this custom event. This tag would also pick up the utm parameters from the dataLayer and forward them to Google Analytics using the "Fields to Set" section of the tag configuration in the GTM interface.